# When to use then: then: while writing Spock tests?

Tags: spock

I am wondering when is it a good practice to write double **then**: **then**: clause while writing **Spock** test? For example

```
def 'some test'() {
   given:
   // Setup
   when:
   //work

   then:
   //Check condition 1
   then:
   //Check condition 2
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`then-then` allows to describe the expected order between mock interactions. (For details, see http://docs.spockframework.org.) Other than that, it's the same as `then-and`, which can sometimes be useful to clearly separate conditions and/or give them separate descriptions.